# SQL heavy query with Zend Framework

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework

I'm here again with another SQL problem.

I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE cities(  
 city_id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
 city_name  TEXT,
 city_lat TEXT,
 city_long TEXT
 ); 

CREATE TABLE entries(
 entry_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
 city_name TEXT
 );
```

Here is the fun part.

I'm trying to make a search by radius, meaning that I want to get the names of the cities in a 10km (for exemple) radius of the city I'm looking for.

The query would be something like

```
 SELECT * FROM entries WHERE entries.city_name LIKE [all the cities in the radius].
```

I have a SQL query to get the cities corresponding to what I want which is:

```
SELECT `city_name`, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians($cooLat) ) * cos( radians( city_lat ) ) * cos( radians( city_long) - radians($cooLong) ) + sin( radians($cooLat) ) * sin( radians( city_lat) ) ) ) AS distance FROM cities HAVING distance < $radius ORDER BY distance
```

$cooLong and $cooLat are php variables that I pass in the function calling that request.

so from that select I get a rowset, but I don't know how to mix the 2 to get my final query that will use the results of the second query in the first one.

Anyway, even if I get through that first problem, I'll have an unknown number of matches. 
Will I have to generate the request by doing something like:

```
SELECT * FROM entries WHERE entries.city_name LIKE 'name_a' OR entries.city_name LIKE 'name_b' OR entries.city_name LIKE 'name_c' ...
```

and that for each one of the cities ?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using spatial data types and indexes for this kind of stuff:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/spatial-extensions.html